# JMeter - Disable/Ignore assertion only for first request

Tags: jmeter

I have a Thread Group with 10+ requests in same hierarchy.

I added [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion)  for all and it's working fine, except in 1 case:

If server is upload before test, first request failed due long duration caused by a server startup delay.

How can I ignore assertion in first request on the first execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan and use the code like:

```
if (prev.getSampleLabel().equals('First Sampler') && vars.getIteration() == 1) {
   prev.setSuccessful(true)
}
```

It will mark the sampler with label of `First Sampler` as successful if it fails during first [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration.

`prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, check out JavaDoc for available functions and properties. For example you might be interested in [getAssertionResults()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getAssertionResults--)